Symbolize one band mosaic dataset with unique values
I have many rasters of 8 bit unsigned integer data type which I want to symbolize using Unique values. When I add the rasters individually to the map I have that option:

I want to add them all to a Mosaic dataset, but then there is no Unique values option. I have tried both with default settings and specifying data type when creating the Mosaic:

How can I create a Mosaic dataset with the option to use Unique Values symbology?

I've played around with the mosaic settings and could not get it to offer up a unique symbology option. This page gives a hint to the available rendering options a mosaic dataset allows.
But I did come up with a fudge that worked for me, may be its good enough for your needs?

Create the mosaic dataset.
Load in your raster datasets
In catalog Pane, right on mosaic dataset > Enhance > Calculate Statistics
You now have Classify as an option in the Symbology Pane and set that to the number of classes you have in your integer raster.

